# as I type on SO Title,the result shows up nicely with loading effect and with a fit box that displays result, how do I make it like that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set all the backend, so when I type something in my search bar it shows up the result(eg if I type t, then test shows up) but I want this to be displayed nicely in a box and hopefully with loading effect. If the result overflows, a scroll bar would be also nice too.

I have this in my navbar

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" onkeyup="handle_keyup()"/></div>
      </form>
```

the result is being shown with this

```
<ul id="search-results">

</ul>
```

simple code, but only problem is when I type "t", then the result "test" shows up as if the whole screen is moving down once. I want them to be displayed nicely in a fit box like StackOverflow....

Comment: @Rajesh yeah I'm calling ajax, and it works great. are you saying I need to touch ajax to display it nicely as well? the whole functionality works, just want the results to be displayed nicely in a box like stack overflow title insert box

Comment: No.  Then my bad. You will have to use css for that.

Comment: @Rajesh any idea how?